# How to find the correct graph for variation of capacitance with time.?

Tags: capacitor

First of all I have to admit that this is a homework type question.  Figure below shows  you the question

[image]

---

### My thoughts towards this question

Capacitance for parallel plate capacitor  is given by the following formula

[image]

So here when you insert the dielectric material what is the parameter that is going to be varied? I believe the distance between the plates are varying. But I am not quite sure about that.

Anyways the answer in the answer script is fourth one. I don't know how they get it.So I seek your help

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it will help with visualisation to consider the slightly simpler case of a rectangular cut-out, frozen in time with a length, x, of the cut-out between the plates, as below. Assume the depth of the cross-section is 1, so the total area of the top plate, for example, is \$A=L*1=L\$.

This can be modelled by the capacitor arrangement shown below the cross-section (perhaps if you imagine a fictitious thin conductor plate separating the two smaller rectangles it will convince you that they are two capacitors acting in series).

The question, as set, does not need mathematical analysis as it's just looking for qualitative judgement, however, it may be worthwhile going some way towards developing a mathematical model...

... using the formula for capacitance: \$C=\frac{\epsilon_r \epsilon_o  Area}{Distance}\$, the various capacitor values are: \$C_1=\frac{\epsilon_r \epsilon_o (L-x)}{D}\$; \$C_2=\frac{\epsilon_r \epsilon_o x}{D-d}\$; \$C_3=\frac{\epsilon_o x}{d}\$

Hence the overall capacitance is \$C=C_1 + \frac{C_2 C_3}{C_2+C_3}\$, and the effects of each term, as the dielectric moves through the plates, can be determined by letting x increase progressively from zero.

Not a particularly easy formula to evaluate, but it's easier than the triangular cut-out which results in a logarithmic relationship, as it involves integration of terms of the forms \$1/x\$ and \$1/(x+a)\$

[image]

Comment: How you get those values for C1 and other things.I mean what is the capacitor here, what are the two plates responsible

Comment: C1 is the larger dark grey rectangle (dimension {L-x} by D), C2 is the smaller dark grey rectangle (dimension x by {D-d}) , and C3 is the small light grey rectangle (dimension x by d).

Comment: ... perhaps if you consider a fictitious thin conductor plate separating the two smaller rectangles it will convince you that they are two capacitors acting in series.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to think through this is just to imagine the dielectric constant in your formula:

[image: capacitance]

parameter d is constant (plate separation).

parameter A is constant    (plate area).

parameter epsilon is varying (stuff between the plates). The dielectric of the "capacitor" is a sort of sum of the two materials (dielectric and air).  When a gap appears in the dielectric the net permittivity decreases, resulting in a lower capacitance.  The opposite is true for the small sharp peaks.  In that case there is more dielectric between the plates, so capacitance increases.

[image: capacitance]

(src: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/capacitor/cap_1.html )

Comment: What does the parameter A denotes. I am pretty confused it.Is it the surface area of the plates or what is it?

Comment: @Onthewaytosuccess Yes it would be the overlapping surface area of the plates.  Since the plates are not moving relative to each other at all in this scenario you can assume it will remain constant.

Comment: But what does the overlapping area mean?

Comment: @Onthewaytosuccess I added a diagram.  It is hard to tell in your specific homework question, but 'A' is the actual plate area in square meters.

Comment: Isn't the area changing?

Comment: It means we take A as the area of the conductive plate? Can you give me a example where area is changing

Comment: @Onthewaytosuccess How would it? The capacitor plates aren't moving at all.  Just the stuff in between them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25802/discussion-between-justing-and-on-the-way-to-success).

Answer (score 1):

The capacitance is proportional to the *total volume* of dielectric between the plates plus a constant capacitance offset.

So you can derive following rules that help you to identify the correct capacitance-vs-time pattern:

- Capacitance **decreases** when

  - a trench enters or
  - a wedge leaves 
    the area between the plates.
- Capacitance **increases** when

  - a wedge enters or
  - a trench leaves
    the area between the plates.

Comment: Why the capacitance change  like that ?

Comment: Air or vacuum has low epsilon. Dielectric material has high epsilon. C is proportinal to total epsilon (given that A and d stays the same, which is the case). Total epsilon increases/decreases with increasing/decreasing proportion of dielectric material between the plates.

Comment: Then, if we have more =dielectric inside a capacitor ,capacitance of that is  high   compared to the less dielectric in same capacitor